# How to check for FileError in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

On a Ionic Cordova project there's an error thrown and when caught, I want to check if it's of type FileError.

However the following doesn't work in Typescript, it complains that FileError is not defined.

If I run it in Chrome's developer tools, it works.

```
if(error instanceof FileError) {
   //show message
}
```

Edit: I cannot change to avoid using FileError because we are using Ionic Native library and it uses FileError when throwing errors. I just need a way to determine the type of error thrown by this library in catch block for error handling.

Answer (score 1):

It says in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileError) that it's an obsolete feature, you might want to use [`FileReader.error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/error) instead

Comment: I cannot change to use this because we are using Ionic Native library and it uses FileError when throwing errors. I just need a way to determine the type of error thrown by this library in catch block for error handling.

Comment: Then manually declare FileError in your ts file, you don't have too many much options here